# textviews in table.i want user input on those textviews on a submit button click

Tags: android, tablelayout

I want to set user input to the textviews in a tablelayout for a word game application.i am new to android please help me through this.

```
        tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tablelparam = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(30,30);

        for (int r = 1; r <=9; r++) {
            r1= new TableRow(this);
            r1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            for (int c = 1; c<=5; c++) {
                TextView txtview=new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                txtview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                txtview.setId(counter);
                counter++;
                txtview.setText( +counter + inputWord);
                r1.addView(txtview);
            }
            tl.addView(r1,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<String>words = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < words.size(); j++) {
                TextView txtview = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                txtview.setId(j);
                txtview.setText("" + words.get(j));
                txtview.getLayoutParams();
                t3.setText(t3.getText() + " " + txtview.getText()); 

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the onClickListener() for each TextView you instantiate inside your for loop.

Comment: I want to match the user string with the database and then set that user string to the textviews in the table. Is it possible to fetch all records from database into an arraylist and then setText to the textviews?

Comment: Of course, you could even use a GridView instead of a TableLayout and then use a CursorAdapter to map your DB values to each cell of the GridView.